# shell Can't exit while loop normally.

Tags: shell, if-statement, while-loop

```
$ cat Judge_file.sh
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while [ $i ];do
    read -p "Enter your MO or attribute name: " name
    if [ $name = "q" ];then
        i=0
        continue
    else
        grep -q $name *.txt    #check character existence in currently directory of all .txt file
        if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
            echo "Name exists,send to file 2"
            echo $name >> 2.txt
        else
            echo "Name missing,send to file 1"
            echo $name >> 1.txt
        fi
    fi
done
$ . ./Judge_file.sh
Enter your MO or attribute name: chenghuang
Name exists,send to file 2
Enter your MO or attribute name: llkk
Name missing,send to file 1
Enter your MO or attribute name: q
Enter your MO or attribute name: q
Enter your MO or attribute name: q
```

This is a program used for judge a character existence.

When I type "q", it should be exited. but why it still let me input.

and one thing really strange when I verified the `while [ $i ]` as `while [ 0 ]` ,then while loop still let me input , until I type Ctrl+c exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'll pick the important part of your script for the problem:

Instead:

```
...
if [ $name = "q" ];then
    i=0
    continue
else
...
```

you should have:

```
...
if [ $name = "q" ];then
    i=0
    break
else
...
```

Then the script will terminate when you press the `q` key.

The `continue` continues to the end of the loop.  If you want to terminate the while loop you have to use `break`.

**First edit**
Based on the comment I think you misunderstood the bash `[]` meaning.

The `while [0]` is same as `tests 0`.  Which is always true and thus leading to a endless loop.

I would really recommend using true/false instead of 1/0.  To rewrite your code with `continue`:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=true
while $i;do
    read -p "Enter your MO or attribute name: " name
    if [ $name = "q" ];then
        i=false
        continue
    else
        grep -q $name *.txt    #check character existence in currently directory of all .txt file
        if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
            echo "Name exists,send to file 2"
            echo $name >> 2.txt
        else
            echo "Name missing,send to file 1"
            echo $name >> 1.txt
        fi
    fi
done
```

If you insist on using 1/0 you can do it as following

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while (( $i ));do
    read -p "Enter your MO or attribute name: " name
    if [ $name = "q" ];then
        i=0
        continue
    else
        grep -q $name *.txt    #check character existence in currently directory of all .txt file
        if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
            echo "Name exists,send to file 2"
            echo $name >> 2.txt
        else
            echo "Name missing,send to file 1"
            echo $name >> 1.txt
        fi
    fi
done
```

Now it probably behaves like you would expect 0 as false and 1 as true.

Comment: Okkkkk,, thank you it works ,but why I change the `while [ &i ]` as `while [ 0 ]` , the while loop still running?

Comment: I think you got mixed with the brackets.  The issue here is that in bash while [0] means a test.  e.g. testing 0 is true.  If you want to end you have to either use `while false` or `while ((0))`.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: YES, I see. if I use `while( ( &i ))` , and keep using `continue`, it will work when I  press  `q` key. The `continue` use to jump to the next loop. but in this program only has one `while` loop , So, when I press `q`, the loop will execute `i=0` than jump to `while (( $i ))` (the $i=0), So, it means `while(false)`, than break the loop. This is my understanding, am I right?

Comment: @huangcheng you are welcome. The keyword `continue` jumps to the end while and then evaluates the condition.  In case is `while (( 0 ))` it will terminate the loop as it will evaluate it as `false`.  The `break` keyword will terminate the while loop immediately.